# Cannot Find The Specified File for Vlc.DotNet.Core

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a vlc project in c#. In my project I have a folder stucture like so:

```
D:\Projects\Lane\LaneCameraViewer\CameraViewer\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\libvlc\win-x86
```

inside it is where I put several vlc libraries

1. libvlc.dll
2. VcDotNet.Core.dll
3. Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops.dll

Then I try to load this dlls like so:

using (var mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
{

```
            var mediaOptions = new[]
            {
            ":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://172.16.35.71:8008/test}",
            ":sout-keep"
        };
   .....
}
```

But on the var `mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory)`, I get an error of `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Unable to find the specified file.'`